# Как отличить interface{} от []interface{}

Tags: golang

Тут такой вопрос, есть пример:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func detect(data interface{}) {
    if _, ok := data.([]interface{}); ok {
        fmt.Println(data, "is array")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(data, "is scalar")
    }
}
func main() {
    detect("foo")
    detect([]string{"bar"})
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/j5n9o6BT3i

Собственно как можно отличать скалярные величины от массивов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/).

```
func detect(data interface{}) {
    k := reflect.ValueOf(data).Kind()
    if k == reflect.Array || k == reflect.Slice {
        fmt.Println(data, "is array")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(data, "is scalar")
    }
}
```

Comment: А без reflection можно? Просто мне кажется что в случае использования reflection большме накладные расходы

Answer (score 2):

Может вам просто [type switch](https://github.com/Konstantin8105/Effective_Go_RU/blob/master/README.md#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-type-switch) нужен. Вы наверняка будете знать список возможных типов заранее.

Пример: https://play.golang.org/p/8PpDC68fGD

```golang
func detect(data interface{}) {
    switch d:=data.(type) {
    case []string:
        fmt.Println(d, "is array")
    case string:
        fmt.Println(d, "is scalar")
    }
}
```

Comment: Там слишком большой `switch` получается, все скалярные типы перечислять в виде массивов: `int`, `int64`, `uint`, `uint64` и т.д.

Comment: Тогда только reflect...